# Is possible to add entities to a group programmatically in Home Assistant?

Tags: python, home-assistant

I want to know if there is a way to add entities to a group programmatically using Python?

Answer (score 0):

After surf and watch the source code of Home assistant I found the solution and there are 2 ways:

`import homeassistant.components.group as group`

`test_group = group.Group.create_group(
hass, 'your_group', ['device_tracker.your_device'])`

and this other way:

`hass.states.set('group.your_group', 'on', {
        'entity_id': ['device_tracker.csp1_zte_com_cn', 'device_tracker.your_device']})`

I prefer the last one but both were tested and worked perfectly